# Detailed Disclosures for Different table view cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifierHere" sender:self];
}
```

This is Work for All table Cell for the Table at a Particular View Controller.
can anyone help me , if i just want to use different Segue for different Cell , what is the Best way to separate the Cells .

Comment: can you add more detail? I am not sure what you are trying to ask

Comment: sure i have 5 -6 Different Segues that i want to connect with Different "Detailed Disclosure Buttons for the Table view Cells . but the Above Code is working for All the Cell , so how i can differentiate the Cell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.row == 0)
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifierHere" sender:self];
   else if (indexPath.row == 1)
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSecondSegueIdentifierHere" sender:self];
   else if (indexPath.row == 2)
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourThirdSegueIdentifierHere" sender:self];
}
```

or you can opt for a `switch (indexPath.row)` also in this case.

`indexPath` is unique for each cell and `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` can be used to differentiate between different cells in different sections.

Comment: Awesome :)  if ((indexPath.row == 9) && (indexPath.section == 1))

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it or test it but if such method exists a simple switch case or if/else block would be enough I guess

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
   case 0:
   { 
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegue1" sender:self];
       break;
   }
    case 1:
   { 
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegue2" sender:self];
       break;
   }
    case 2:
   { 
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegue3" sender:self];
       break;
   }
   default:
       break; 
}       

}
```